# How to Send multiple Json objects by using volley in android

Tags: android, json, post, android-volley

I want to send this json data using post method in volley
here is multiple json objects with different tag name

```
 [{"name":"hi","address":"home","Language":"English"},
 {"name":"hello","address":"house","Language":"English"},
 {"name":"man","address":"India","Language":"Hindi"}]
```

Below is my working code here i'm sending single json objects  , can anyone help me.
Thanks in advance.

```
      private void sendMessage() {

     final Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
    String tag_json_obj = "json_obj_req";
    //String url = "http://192.168.0.106:59181/api/Employees";
    String url = "http://android.azurewebsites.net/kfdgf/Employees";

    final ProgressDialog pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    pDialog.setMessage("Senting message...");
    pDialog.show();

    StringRequest req = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {

                    pDialog.hide();

                    pDialog.hide();
                    // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"hi", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Log.d("", response);

                    finish();


                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            VolleyLog.d("", "Error: " + error.getMessage());
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            pDialog.hide();

            // hide the progress dialog

        }
    }) {

        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();

            params.put("name", name);

            params.put("address", agentId);
            params.put("Language", count);
            return params;
        }

    };

}
```

Comment: Using JSONArray you can send multiple JSONObject

Ex: Multiple JSONObject in one single JSONArray  and then JSONArray Pass into your API

Answer (score 2):

Bad programming practice.

These JSON objects can send one by one only, by looping the service calls.

if you want to send this JSON object in one shot then follow some standard structure of JSON. Create and JSON array of objects and pass it to api in one shot.

standard JSON format to pass multiple objects into single shot,

```
{
"data": [{
    "name": "hi",
    "address": "home",
    "Language": "English"
}, {
    "name": "hello",
    "address": "house",
    "Language": "English"
}, {
    "name": "man",
    "address": "India",
    "Language": "Hindi"
}]
```

}

Comment: can you please tell how to pass it to an api one shot

Comment: how to send this json data do you have any idea?

Comment: im able to send only one time means first objects

Comment: if anyone have this code kindly share it please i have same issue i cant fetch value in response